# How do I print Kotlin Class properties to Logcat in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I am writing a simple program to describe the attributes of my favorite song, namely: artistName, songTitle, releaseDate, etc. I have created a class 'FavoriteSong' and added some properties to represent these attributes. When I run the code, I would like the class properties to be printed to Logcat. How can I achieve this?

```
package com.example.song

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.Month

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Favorite Song
        class FavoriteSong {
            val artistName: String = "Wale" 
            val songTitle: String = "My World" 
            val releaseDate = LocalDate.of(2020, Month.JANUARY, 1)
            val songDuration: Float = 3.50f 
            val genre: String = "Reggae" 
        }
        
        // Why won't this Log.d() statement work?
        Log.d(FavoriteSong)
    }
}
```

Comment: All caps title makes it look like you're yelling at us.

Comment: Please try to be more accurate when you say "it is not working". Do you have an error (which one?) or does it simply not behave the way you intend?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not well-versed in Android anymore (and more specifically I don't recall `Log.d()`'s signature), but I see several potential problems here:

- `FavoriteSong` is a class, not an object. You need to create an instance of it by calling the constructor: `FavoriteSong()` (note the parentheses immediately after the class name)
- if `Log.d()` needs a string, you probably need to call `.toString()` on your `FavoriteSong` instance. If it accepts `Any`, you should be ok as it will most likely call `toString()` under the hood
- your current definition of `FavoriteSong` does not override `Any`'s `toString()` method. You need to either declare an `override fun toString(): String = ...` yourself, or make this class a `data class` so that it generates one for you automatically